# How to prevent "tree" from printing directories that don't match the given pattern?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use `tree` to print the files that match the given pattern. First of all, the structure of the current directory is as follows.

```
$tree .
.
├── a
├── search.sh
└── test.java

1 directory, 2 files
```

Notice that `a` is an empty directory.

I want `tree` to print all the files that match the pattern `*.sh`, here's what I've tried.

```
$tree -P "*.sh"
.
├── a
└── search.sh

1 directory, 1 file
```

I couldn't figure out why `tree` also printed `a`, which is a directory and doesn't match the given pattern? How to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Have a look at `--matchdirs` and `--prune` attributes in `man tree`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man tree` says:

> Tree does not prune "empty" directories when the -P and -I options are used by default. Use the --prune option.

*empty* means *doesn't contain a matching file* here.

So the following should work:

```
tree -P '*.sh' --prune
```

```
$ mkdir a
$ touch search.sh
$ touch a/a
$ tree -P '*.sh' --prune
.
└── search.sh

0 directories, 1 file
```